# Access local file by IP address

Tags: objective-c

I want to access my local file by using IP address of my own PC(like 192.168.0.65/file.txt). Is there anything that can make it in objective c?
and another thing is, is it work for another local server too?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"pathToFile"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: That needs a file:// URL. I guess what the OP asks for is simply nonsense.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation around your answer, rather than just pasting code?